# css element selecting not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a html code snippet.

```css
[title~="ab"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div title="ab">I am div</div>
<div>
  <p>I am p1</p>
</div>
<p title="abc">I am p2</p>
<p>I am p3</p>
<div>
  <p title="ab">I am p4</p>
</div>
```

I know css selector `[title~=ab]` should have select all title value which containing value `ab`, if this is correct, why `I am p2` is not selected?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: use * instead of  tiled  
        [title*="ab"] {
            color: red;
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[title*="ab"]` rather than `[title~="ab"]`. `*` is contains whereas `~` is contains word, as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).